# How to I make QMessageBox delete the content of a vector

Tags: c++, user-interface, vector, qmessagebox

I'm very new to code so I apologise if this is a simple question but I am struggling.
I have a GUI program that saves user input into a vector, displays it then can be saved as a txt file. Once it has been saved, I want a QMessageBox to appear asking if the user wishes to delete the now saved vector data. The vector is named v_History.

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("History saved to file.");
msgBox.setInformativeText("Would you like to delete the current history?");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard);
msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Discard);
msgBox.exec();
```

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Look at the example in the documentation: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html) starting with `switch(ret) {` you need to do `auto ret = msgBox.exec();`  or `int ret = msgBox.exec();` instead of `msgBox.exec();` then use the same technique as the documentation.

Comment: Thank you - I have made some progress but still cannot figure out how to assign the outcome I need once the buttons are pressed. I have something like this at the moment which, of course, does not work - but it is close to what I want to achieve:

`msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::No);
int ret = msgBox.exec();

msgBox.exec();
if (QMessageBox::Yes.clicked() == clear.v_history) {
} else if`

Comment: @TheNuck you are calling `msgBox.exec()` twice.  Call it only once. And then compare the value it returns, eg: `int ret = msgBox.exec(); if (ret == QMessageBox::Yes) { /* clear the history here */ }`

Answer (score 2):

When using `setStandardButtons()`, `exec()` returns a value indicating which standard button was clicked, eg:

```cpp
QMessageBox msgBox;
msgBox.setText("History saved to file.");
msgBox.setInformativeText("Would you like to delete the current history?");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Save | QMessageBox::Discard);
msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Discard);
int ret = msgBox.exec();
if (ret == QMessageBox::Discard)
{
    // delete the history as needed ...
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working now, thank you all so much!